# Sorting linked list from biggest to smallest

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have sorted my linked list with this code.

It sorts it from smallest to biggest due to `data2`.

e.g: my list's output was :

```
1. data1: 3 data2: 4
2. data1: 7 data2: 3
3. data1: 5 data2: 0
4. data1:-6 data2: 2
5. data1: 4 data2: 1
```

and it made it to this:

```
1. data1: 5 data2: 0
2. data1: 4 data2: 1
3. data1:-6 data2: 2
4. data1: 7 data2: 3
5. data1: 3 data2: 4
```

It works right but I want it to sort it from biggest to smallest.

If changed this line `if (iterbub->us > iterbub->next->us)` to
`if (iterbub->us < iterbub->next->us)` this but it worked like this:

```
1. data1: 3435431 data2: 7343443
2. data1: 3 data2: 4
3. data1: 7 data2: 3
4. data1:-6 data2: 2
5. data1: 4 data2: 1
```

It looks like there is a little problem how can I fix that?
(first doesn't look fine)

```
typedef struct node{
    int katsayi;
    int us;
    struct node *next;
} Polinomlar;    

void degistir(Polinomlar *a, Polinomlar *b) {
    int temp = a->us;
    a->us = b->us;
    b->us = temp;

    int temp2 = a->katsayi;
    a->katsayi = b->katsayi;
    b->katsayi = temp2;
}

void sirala(Polinomlar *p3)
{
    int degisim, i;
    node *iterbub;

    if (p3 == NULL)
        return;
    do
    {
        degisim = 0;
        iterbub = p3;

        while (iterbub->next != NULL)
        {
            if (iterbub->us > iterbub->next->us)
            {
                degistir(iterbub, iterbub->next);
                degisim = 1;
            }
            iterbub = iterbub->next;
        }
    } while (degisim);
}
```

Comment: BTW: linked lists and merge sort are natural partners.

Comment: Also, when swapping values, you swap `->katsayi`, but you forget to swap `->us`.

Comment: @wildplasser  i did it in degistir() function

Comment: @DenizAkpınar which algorithm are you using?

Comment: @suvojit_007 bubblesort, obviously.

Comment: @suvojit_007 yes, bubblesort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this `if (iterbub->us > iterbub->next->us)` to `if (iterbub->us < iterbub->next->us)` as you want to sort in descending order.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct node{
    int katsayi;
    int us;
    struct node *next;
} Polinomlar;    

void degistir(Polinomlar *a, Polinomlar *b) {
    int temp = a->us;
    a->us = b->us;
    b->us = temp;

    int temp2 = a->katsayi;
    a->katsayi = b->katsayi;
    b->katsayi = temp2;
}

void sirala(Polinomlar *p3)
{
    int degisim, i;
    Polinomlar *iterbub;

    if (p3 == NULL)
        return;
    do
    {
        degisim = 0;
        iterbub = p3;

        while (iterbub->next != NULL)
        {
            if (iterbub->us < iterbub->next->us)
            {
                degistir(iterbub, iterbub->next);
                degisim = 1;
            }
            iterbub = iterbub->next;
        }
    }while (degisim);
}


int main()
{

Polinomlar* x = (Polinomlar*)malloc(sizeof(Polinomlar));
x->katsayi = 5;
x->us = 10;
x->next = (Polinomlar*)malloc(sizeof(Polinomlar));

x->next->katsayi = 5;
x->next->us = 20;
x->next->next = (Polinomlar*)malloc(sizeof(Polinomlar));
x->next->next->katsayi = 15;
x->next->next->us = 30;
x->next->next->next = NULL;


sirala(x);

Polinomlar* x1 = x;

while(x1!=NULL)
{
 printf("%d  " , x1->us);   
x1 = x1->next;    
}

}
```

> Output: 30 20 10

Comment: and i lost my first line of linked list

Comment: @DenizAkpınar I tested the above code. It's working fine.

Comment: but why am i losing first node of the linked list :( whats ur idea? i need help

Comment: @DenizAkpınar Try checking your main method twice where you have declared nodes. I have tested the above code and it's giving the desired result.

Comment: @DenizAkpınar Did you find your mistake? If not, then you need to post the rest of your code.

Comment: thank you for your help i converted "while (iterbub->next != NULL)" this to "while (iterbub->next-> next!= NULL)" this and it fixed the code